# MackBook Pro Clean Install Issue?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, install

Recently, my HDD went bad in my laptop, so I bought a new HDD and a copy of Snow Leopard.

I put the HDD into the computer, then inserted the installation disk into the DVD drive. I went into Disk utility, then created a partition for Mac OSX extended (journal) then, started the install. It said 29 mins, then I got a install failure saying that it had an error copying over the support files.

What did I do wrong?

Also NOTE: the screen looked glitch-y. Some parts looked wierd on the screen, like a Graphics driver was not installed.

Comment: There may be multiple reasons for the failure, broken or damaged installation disc, failing hard drive, etc... Do you get the same error when you retry the installation (after rebooting, of course) ?

Comment: Yes, i do. This is my 3rd time. And still failure.

Comment: Do i need a previous version of OSX to install this version of OSX?

Comment: Is the installation disk damaged or scratched ? And no, you don't need a previous version to install this one.

Comment: No it is not...

Comment: Reformat the HDD again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have the reputation to comment yet.

Is this a standalone copy of SL or is it from someone else's Mac? The included disk with another system is not guaranteed to work with a different model of Mac.

Have your tried erasing the HDD again from Disk Utility, be sure to select the drive(not the indented logic drive) and let it rebuild the GUID again.

You can also try an NVRAM reset before running the Installation([Instructions Here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379)) in hopes that will solve the video issues you run into.